# libxml2 fails on xsd schema validation for element type anyURI containing special characters like "[", "["

Tags: xml, validation, go, xsd, libxml2

I am using [go-libxml2](https://github.com/lestrrat/go-libxml2) for my xsd schema validation. I have an XML element  which takes url as a value. My xsd also contains its type as anyURI as follows

```
<xs:element name="url" type="xs:anyURI">
```

The following code throws error on validation url which contains "[]"

```
xsd.schema.Validate(xml)
```

The following is the sample url which throws an error

```
<url>
    <![CDATA[
        http://example.com/orda/var[div]=super
    ]]>
</url>
```

Error:

```
'http://example.com/orda/var[div]=super is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:anyURI'
```

Regular urls are working fine. Any idea how to solve this issue

Comment: [Square brackets are not allowed in the path component of a URI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3). Your validator is correct and the solution is to put a valid URI into your document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (emphasis mine):

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
> [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
> within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is **the only place where
> square bracket characters are allowed** in the URI syntax.

Try replacing them with `%5b` and `%5d`, respectively.